# Relation between EXTJS and JSON

Tags: extjs

Am new to EXTJS.

Can anyone explain me the relation between `EXTJS` and `JSON`. 
From my understanding, this is what I have understood.

**EXTJS** is a framework and **JSON** is one of the many programming languages that can be used in that Framework.

Something similar to `.net` framework where we can use many programming languages like `VB`, `C++`, `C#`, and so on.

Is this right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ExtJS is a framework indeed but the language it uses is JavaScript. ExtJS can consume objects expressed in JSON but JSON is NOT a programming language, it's a way to express objects, hence the name JavaScript Object Notation, see here for more information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON